# Access secured Mongodb using Stratio python API with credentials

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to read collection from mongodb which is secured. I use spark context in my python script (PySpark) and it includes the following query:

```
df_collec = sqlContext.read.format("com.stratio.datasource.mongodb").
            options(host='server_ip:port', database='db1', collection='collec_1', 
            credentials = 'username,db1,password').load()
```

I am executing the following spark job:

```
bin/spark-submit --packages com.stratio.datasource:spark-mongodb_2.11:0.12.0 
                 --master local[1] python_script.py
```

But I am getting this error:

```
 py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o33.load.
: com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "34.207.228.12:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "Authentication failed." , "code" : 18 , "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed"}
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:76)
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:140)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort$SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(DBPort.java:899)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.authenticate(DBPort.java:432)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.checkAuth(DBPort.java:443)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:289)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:269)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.find(DBCollectionImpl.java:84)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:320)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:299)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.getStats(DBCollection.java:1808)
    at com.mongodb.casbah.MongoCollectionBase$class.getStats(MongoCollection.scala:608)
    at com.mongodb.casbah.MongoCollection.getStats(MongoCollection.scala:1162)
    at com.mongodb.casbah.MongoCollectionBase$class.stats(MongoCollection.scala:606)
    at com.mongodb.casbah.MongoCollection.stats(MongoCollection.scala:1162)
    at com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.partitioner.MongodbPartitioner.isShardedCollection(MongodbPartitioner.scala:79)
    at com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.partitioner.MongodbPartitioner$$anonfun$computePartitions$1.apply(MongodbPartitioner.scala:67)
    at com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.partitioner.MongodbPartitioner$$anonfun$computePartitions$1.apply(MongodbPartitioner.scala:66)
    at com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.util.usingMongoClient$.apply(usingMongoClient.scala:27)
    at com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.partitioner.MongodbPartitioner.computePartitions(MongodbPartitioner.scala:66)
    at com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.rdd.MongodbRDD.getPartitions(MongodbRDD.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$.defaultPartitioner(Partitioner.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$reduceByKey$3.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$reduceByKey$3.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.reduceByKey(PairRDDFunctions.scala:327)
    at com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.schema.MongodbSchema.schema(MongodbSchema.scala:46)
    at com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.MongodbRelation.com$stratio$datasource$mongodb$MongodbRelation$$lazySchema$lzycompute(MongodbRelation.scala:63)
    at com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.MongodbRelation.com$stratio$datasource$mongodb$MongodbRelation$$lazySchema(MongodbRelation.scala:60)
    at com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.MongodbRelation$$anonfun$1.apply(MongodbRelation.scala:65)
    at com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.MongodbRelation$$anonfun$1.apply(MongodbRelation.scala:65)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.MongodbRelation.<init>(MongodbRelation.scala:65)
    at com.stratio.datasource.mongodb.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:345)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I read couple of blogs where it was suggested that it could be due to a user not having a certain privilege to run splitVector command in MongoDB. This command is used for partitioning the collection to store it on multiple nodes. I followed through on that and asked the administrator to assign me 'clusterManager' role. 

But still not resolved.